# How to find the version of Trend from the Registry of a specific PC?

Tags: powershell, registry

I was wondering if there is a way to find a registry value of a specific computer. The only way I could find is entering a pssession and then exiting.

```
$Computer = Read-Host "Enter the PC Name: "


$connection=test-connection -ComputerName  $Computer -Quiet
if($connection -eq $True) {




Enter-PSSession $Computer


$TrendServer= Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TrendMicro\PC-cillinNTCorp \CurrentVersion | Select Server
write-output $TrendServer



if($TrendServer -ne $null){
Exit-PSSession
 }
 } else{Write-Output "Computer is not available. Please check Lan Sweeper "}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is installed using Windows Installer, you can use WMI, though this class is known to be quite slow:

```
Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = 'TrendMicro'" `
                -ComputerName $computer
```

Change the name from 'TrendMicro' to whatever it actually is (I don't have it installed to check), and for older versions of PowerShell, use `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance`.

Get more information here: [Working with Software Installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-6)

Comment: It may not be using the WI.  Is it listed if you just use: `Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product"`?

Comment: Ahh it is there as "Trend Micro OfficeScan Agent"  for the Name. Is that what I need to replace in your code?

Comment: Yes, change the query to `"SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = 'Trend Micro OfficeScan Agent'"`

Comment: That  definitely pulled some information however it does not provide the data I need. It shows the Name, Caption, Vendor, Version, IdentifyingNubmer, and Computer Name.  In my code it pulls the server name that is related to what Trend server a given PC is using. I tried adding "| Select Server" at the end of the code above with no luck

Comment: Yeah, this only gets the generic install details.  Sounds like the thing you want is Trend-specific, so unless Trend have any cmdline tools or cmdlets you can use, then your current approach with direct registry access looks like the only way.  If you have the Remote Registry service running, you can use [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012207/extract-registry-value-from-multiple-computers-using-powershell) to access it without going through PowerShell Remoting.

Comment: I changed a few variables from that code in the link you just sent and it seems to work. Thanks :)